Website on dark mode change correctly to dark mode and then to light mode on reload
I made a tiny website to try something out and I spent a few hours trying to implement a dark mode in it. The dark mode is correctly working and all but the problem I encounter is when I reload.
I used local storage and it works fine but for some reason the website when in dark mode changes after 0.1s back to light color even though the variable is still on dark.
Could someone help me please, here is the code:
<button onclick="changeTheme()" class="darkswitch"></button>
<main>
  <h1>Testing title</h1>
  <p>hello</p>
</main>

let currentTheme = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("theme"));
console.log(currentTheme);

function setTheme() {
  document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', currentTheme);
}

function changeTheme() {
  if (currentTheme === 'dark') {
    currentTheme = 'light';
  } else {
    currentTheme = 'dark';
  }
  console.log(currentTheme);
  localStorage.setItem("theme", JSON.stringify(currentTheme));
  setTheme();
}

window.onload = setTheme();

:root[data-theme="light"] {
  --text: #09110f;
  --background: #f4fbf9;
  --primary: #44c1a1;
  --secondary: #85e0c9;
  --accent: #58dfbd;
}

:root[data-theme="dark"] {
  --text: #eef6f4;
  --background: #040b09;
  --primary: #3ebb9c;
  --secondary: #1f7a63;
  --accent: #20a785;
}

body {
  background: var(--background);
  color: var(--text);
  transition: ease-in;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
}

.darkswitch {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background: var(--text);
  border: unset;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 0px 54px 55px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0px -12px 30px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0px 4px 6px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17) 0px 12px 13px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09) 0px -3px 5px;
}

.darkswitch:active {
  transform: scale(0.9);
}

I tried changing the method I used in javascript to other ones but none worked

Your code does not produce the behaviour you describe: https://jsfiddle.net/uaytm1wL/

There should be no need to wait for the window load event to occur (which can be quite "late", regarding the desired functionality here), before you call setTheme. Should not even be necessary, to wait for DOMContentLoaded/ready - document.documentElement will already exist at the point, when your script runs. So just call it directly, after you read the value from localStorage.
